# Python // Regex // Tags

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some text from between

```
</br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_1a<br>TEXT_1b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_2a<br>TEXT_2b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_3a<br>TEXT_3b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_4a<br>TEXT_4b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_5a<br>TEXT_5b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_6a<br>TEXT_6b
```

I used BeautifulSoup (BS4)
`text = first_td.renderContents()
trimmed_text = text.strip()
print trimmed_text`
to extract the text. However, I only get the first text after `<td` tag. Nevertheless I would like to extract all the text in the tags, preferably sorted in columns (array). After I went with BS and it did not work I thought Regex is the way to go. One minor thing, I am an absolute regex amateur...

Any ideas how to get the text out there?

Answer (score 0):

To extract all the text present inside the `td` tag.

```
>>> s = '''<td class="first">TEXT_1a<br>TEXT_1b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_2a<br>TEXT_2b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_3a<br>TEXT_3b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_4a<br>TEXT_4b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_5a<br>TEXT_5b
                                </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_6a<br>TEXT_6b'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('td.first')]
['TEXT_1aTEXT_1b', 'TEXT_2aTEXT_2b', 'TEXT_3aTEXT_3b', 'TEXT_4aTEXT_4b', 'TEXT_5aTEXT_5b', 'TEXT_6aTEXT_6b']
```

Comment: Hey Avinash. This works thank you . Is it possible to put TEXT_1b etc in another array?

Comment: try `[re.findall(r'(?<=>)[^><]+(?=<)',str(i).strip()) for i in soup.select('td.first')]`

Comment: Alright. This seems to put large gaps between the texts. Is it possible to just remove the text at the end (TEXT_2b, TEXT_3b...etc)? Thank you!